# Magento2 problem with redirect. Page work without www but with www i've got "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento-2.2.5, server-setup, redirect-url

As in title when I enter to page http://example.com everything fine but when I type http://www.example.com I've got a message "The page isn’t redirecting properly". I try to change base_url and nothing happened. I try set .htaccess to .htaccess.sample and nothing changed. I try DNS records edit and nothing happened... Maybe can someone help me because I don't know how can I fix this :( I was writing with the support of my server and nobody helped me, unfortunately I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Seems it is an issue with hosting. They will help you

Comment: They didn't help me... They reply to me: "report this problem on magento forum". Great help.